# Convert string parameter in function to variable name in R

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
myfunction <- function(arg1){
  arg1 <- m$value
  coverage_plot <- ggplot(data=m, aes(x=Time, y=arg1, group=Technique, color=Technique)) + geom_line()
```

I want to pass a string argument (e.g., `"Age"`) and assign the `m$value` to `Age`. Currently, in the plot, the y-axis label is shown as `arg1`, which should be `Age`.

I thought about converting the string argument to a variable name by using `as.name` function:

```
var <- as.name(arg1)
var <- m$value
coverage_plot <- ggplot(data=m, aes(x=Time, y=var, group=Technique, color=Technique)) + geom_line()
```

I ended up by having the same issue, which is `var` is shown in the plot rather than `Age`.

I also tried to use the `assign` function as `assign(arg1,m$value)` but didn't work as well.

So the question is how to convert the passed argument to a variable that can be shown in the y-axis label?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Maybe you can simply change the actual column name to whatever you want, plot the data, and then change the column name back to its original name.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `aes_string` function and provide it like this:

`aes_string(x="Time", y=var, group="Technique", color="Technique")`

I assume that `"Time"` and `"Technique"` are names of columns in `m`, not variables.

Comment: Actually `Time` and `Technique` are varaibles.

Comment: Then you need `aes_string(x=Time, y=var, group=Technique, color=Technique)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was very simple. The solution is to change the y axis label to the argument string as:

```
myfunction <- function(arg1){
  yValues <- m$value
  the_plot <- ggplot(data=m, aes(x=Time, y=yValues, group=Technique, color=Technique)) + geom_line() + ylab(arg1)
```